Using LocalDateTime in Java Spring framework, still gives Date,parse() error for MongoDb collection
I want to generate a listing report based on "listing status" and "createdOn" date on the MongoDB collection"processing-status". The "listingStatus" field belongs to a nested collection.
The ListingService method is as follows:-
@Override
public List<ProcessingStatus> getProcessingStatusByListingStatusAndDate(String listingStatus,LocalDateTime startDate, LocalDateTime endDate) {

    Query query = new Query();

    logger.info("UTC Start Date: " + startDate);
    logger.info("UTC End Date: " + endDate);
    
    query.addCriteria(Criteria.where("bookscape.listingStatus").is(listingStatus));
    query.addCriteria(Criteria.where("createdOn").gte(startDate).lte(endDate));
    
    logger.info("Generated Query: " + query);
    logger.info("Generated Query through Serialization: " + SerializationUtils.serializeToJsonSafely(query));
    
    List<ProcessingStatus> ps = mongoTemplate.find(query, ProcessingStatus.class);
    logger.info("Query result size " + ps);
    return mongoTemplate.find(query, ProcessingStatus.class);

}


The controller" will call the service method by using the following method:-
@GetMapping("/filter")public ResponseEntity<?> getProcessingStatusByNestedListingStatusAndDate(
        @RequestParam String listingStatus,
        @RequestParam @DateTimeFormat(iso = DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE_TIME) LocalDateTime  startDate,
        @RequestParam @DateTimeFormat(iso = DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE_TIME) LocalDateTime  endDate) {

    logger.info("Method Parameters ");
    logger.info("Listing Status: " + listingStatus);
    logger.info("Start Date: " + startDate);
    logger.info("End Date: " + endDate);
    
    // Call the service method with the listing status and date range
    List<ProcessingStatus> results =  
             listingReport.getProcessingStatusByListingStatusAndDate("Success", startDate, endDate);
    
    // Output the results
    System.out.println("Results: " + results.size());
    
    if (results.isEmpty()) {
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND)
                     .body(Collections.singletonMap("message", "No records 
                            found matching the filter criteria."));
    } else {
        // Generate CSV report
        byte[] reportBytes = generateCsvReport(results);
    
        // Set headers for the CSV file download
        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM);
        headers.setContentDispositionFormData("filename", 
                                            "processing_statuses_report.csv");
    
        return new ResponseEntity<>(reportBytes, headers, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}

private byte[] generateCsvReport(List<ProcessingStatus> processingStatuses) {

    StringBuilder csvBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    csvBuilder.append("Batch ID, ISBN, Listing Status, Created Date\n");
    for (ProcessingStatus status : processingStatuses) {
        String listingStatus = getStatusListing(status);
        csvBuilder.append(status.getBatchId()).append(",")
                .append(status.getIsbn()).append(",")
                .append(listingStatus).append(",")
                .append(status.getCreatedOn() != null ? 
          status.getCreatedOn().toString() : "").append("\n");
    }
    return csvBuilder.toString().getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);

}

private String getStatusListing(ProcessingStatus status) {
    if (status.getAmazonEasyShip().getAmazonEasyShipDel().getListingStatus() != null)
        return status.getAmazonEasyShip().getAmazonEasyShipDel().getListingStatus();
    else if (status.getAmazonEasyShip().getAmazonEasyShipMum().getListingStatus() != null)
        return status.getAmazonEasyShip().getAmazonEasyShipMum().getListingStatus();
    else if (status.getAmazonFlex().getAmazonFlex().getListingStatus() != null)
        return status.getAmazonFlex().getAmazonFlex().getListingStatus();
    else if (status.getFlipkartHSP().getFlipkartHSP().getListingStatus() != null)
        return status.getFlipkartHSP().getFlipkartHSP().getListingStatus();
    else if (status.getFlipkartLSP().getFlipkartLSP().getListingStatus() != null)
        return status.getFlipkartLSP().getFlipkartLSP().getListingStatus();
    else if (status.getBookscape().getBookscape().getListingStatus() != null)
        return status.getBookscape().getBookscape().getListingStatus();
    else
        return "";
}

Output (first line broken because way too long):-
[2024-06-11 18:08:27,148[0;39m [34mINFO [0;39m [[33mhttp-nio-8099-exec-1[0;39m] :
        Method Parameters[37m2024-06-11 18:08:27,148[0;39m
        [34mINFO [0;39m [[33mhttp-nio-8099-exec-1[0;39m] : Listing
        Status: Success[37m2024-06-11 18:08:27,148[0;39m [34mINFO
        [0;39m [[33mhttp-nio-8099-exec-1[0;39m] : Start Date:
        2024-04-01T00:00[37m2024-06-11 18:08:27,148[0;39m [34mINFO
        [0;39m [[33mhttp-nio-8099-exec-1[0;39m] : End Date:
        2024-06-03T23:59:59[37m2024-06-11 18:08:27,148[0;39m [34mINFO
        [0;39m [[33mhttp-nio-8099-exec-1[0;39m] : UTC Start Date:
        2024-04-01T00:00[37m2024-06-11 18:08:27,149[0;39m [34mINFO
        [0;39m [[33mhttp-nio-8099-exec-1[0;39m] : UTC End Date:
        2024-06-03T23:59:59[37m2024-06-11 18:08:27,151[0;39m [34mINFO
        [0;39m [[33mhttp-nio-8099-exec-1[0;39m] : Generated Query:
        Query: { "bookscape.listingStatus" : "Success"}, Fields: {},
        Sort: {}[37m2024-06-11 18:08:27,151[0;39m [34mINFO [0;39m
        [[33mhttp-nio-8099-exec-1[0;39m] : Generated Query through
        Serialization: { "$java" : Query: { "bookscape.listingStatus"
        : "Success"}, Fields: {}, Sort: {} }[37m2024-06-11
        18:08:27,327[0;39m [1;31mERROR[0;39m
        [[33mhttp-nio-8099-exec-1[0;39m] : Servlet.service() for
        servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw
        exception [Request processing failed:
        org.springframework.core.convert.ConversionFailedException:
        Failed to convert from type [java.lang.String] to type
        [java.util.Date] for value []] with root
        causejava.lang.IllegalArgumentException: null

        at java.base/java.util.Date.parse(Date.java:617)
        at java.base/java.util.Date.<init>(Date.java:275)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:77)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:499)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:480)
        at org.springframework.core.convert.support.ObjectToObjectConverter.convert(ObjectToObjectConverter.java:113)
        at org.springframework.core.convert.support.ConversionUtils.invokeConverter(ConversionUtils.java:41)
        at org.springframework.core.convert.support.GenericConversionService.convert(GenericConversionService.java:182)
        at org.springframework.core.convert.support.GenericConversionService.convert(GenericConversionService.java:165)
        at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.doConvert(MappingMongoConverter.java:1822)
        at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.doConvert(MappingMongoConverter.java:1814)
        at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.getPotentiallyConvertedSimpleRead(MappingMongoConverter.java:1350)
        at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.getPotentiallyConvertedSimpleRead(MappingMongoConverter.java:1324)
        at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter$DefaultConversionContext.convert(MappingMongoConverter.java:2362)
        at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter$ConversionContext.convert(MappingMongoConverter.java:2168)
        at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter$MongoDbPropertyValueProvider.getPropertyValue(MappingMongoConverter.java:1934)
        at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.readProperties(MappingMongoConverter.java:620)
        at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.populateProperties(MappingMongoConverter.java:537)
        at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.read(MappingMongoConverter.java:514)
        at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.readDocument(MappingMongoConverter.java:480)
        at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter$DefaultConversionContext.convert(MappingMongoConverter.java:2359)
        at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter$ConversionContext.convert(MappingMongoConverter.java:2168)
        at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter$MongoDbPropertyValueProvider.getPropertyValue(MappingMongoConverter.java:1934)
        at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.readProperties(MappingMongoConverter.java:620)
        at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.populateProperties(MappingMongoConverter.java:537)
        at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.read(MappingMongoConverter.java:514)
        at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.readDocument(MappingMongoConverter.java:480)
        at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.read(MappingMongoConverter.java:416)
        at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.read(MappingMongoConverter.java:412)
        at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.read(MappingMongoConverter.java:119)
        at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate$ReadDocumentCallback.doWith(MongoTemplate.java:3287)
        at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.executeFindMultiInternal(MongoTemplate.java:2921)
        at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.doFind(MongoTemplate.java:2598)
        at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.doFind(MongoTemplate.java:2577)
        at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.find(MongoTemplate.java:866)
        at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.find(MongoTemplate.java:856)
        at com.reproworks.ms.orchestrator.service.impl.ListingReportServiceImpl.getProcessingStatusByListingStatusAndDate(ListingReportServiceImpl.java:105)
        at com.reproworks.ms.orchestrator.controller.MSPCalculationServiceController.getProcessingStatusByNestedListingStatusAndDate(MSPCalculationServiceController.java:773)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
        at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:354)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:716)
        at com.reproworks.ms.orchestrator.controller.MSPCalculationServiceController$$SpringCGLIB$$0.getProcessingStatusByNestedListingStatusAndDate(<generated>)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:255)
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:188)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:118)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:926)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:831)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1089)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:979)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1014)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:903)
        at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:564)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:885)
        at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:658)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:150)
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:175)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:150)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:175)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:150)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:175)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:150)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.ServerHttpObservationFilter.doFilterInternal(ServerHttpObservationFilter.java:109)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:175)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:150)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:175)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:150)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:167)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:90)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:482)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:115)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:93)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:344)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:391)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:63)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:896)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1736)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:52)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:63)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:840)


I tried to have "LocalDateTime" instead of "Date" field in the "ProcessingStatus" and wherever the "createdOn" is being used.

I also tried to do the UTC conversion as follows:-
// Convert the dates to UTC
ZoneId istZone = ZoneId.of("Asia/Kolkata");
ZoneId utcZone = ZoneId.of("UTC");
ZonedDateTime istStartDateTime
        = ZonedDateTime.ofInstant(startDate.toInstant(), istZone);
ZonedDateTime istEndDateTime =
        ZonedDateTime.ofInstant(endDate.toInstant(), istZone);
Date utcStartDate =
        Date.from(istStartDateTime.withZoneSameInstant(utcZone).toInstant());
Date utcEndDate =
        Date.from(istEndDateTime.withZoneSameInstant(utcZone).toInstant());

List<ProcessingStatus> processingStatuses =
        listingReport.getProcessingStatusByListingStatusAndDate(
               listingStatus, utcStartDate, utcEndDate);

logger.info("Listing Status: " + listingStatus);
logger.info("UTC Start Date: " + utcStartDate);
logger.info("UTC End Date: " + utcEndDate);

Please suggest how to resolve this issue.

Can you please [edit] and fix the formatting?

Can someone help me out to deal with this issue?

You might have gotten a better response if you had posted a contrived MCVE rather than dumping a bunch of code.

Caveat: I do not use Spring, so the following is just my guess…
DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE_TIME expects an offset
In Spring, the constant DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE_TIME is for moments, a date with time-of-day as seen in a particular offset-from-UTC (or perhaps a time zone, I am not sure as I do not use Spring).
To quote the Javadoc:

The most common ISO Date Time Format yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX — for example, "2000-10-31T01:30:00.000-05:00".

In that example, the -05:00 means the time of 1:30 AM is five hours behind UTC. The same moment as viewed in UTC (with an offset of zero hours-minutes-seconds) would be 6:30 AM on the same date.
Your inputs of LocalDateTime have no offset, yet you used DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE_TIME which seems to expect an offset.
LocalDateTime cannot represent a moment
You chose to work with java.time.LocalDateTime objects. That class does not represent a moment. That class represents only a date with time-of-day, but lacks the context of an offset-from-UTC or a time zone.
To represent a moment
If your software is trying to represent a moment, a specific point on the timeline, do not use LocalDateTime. Use Instant, OffsetDateTime, or ZonedDateTime.
